# Covariant derivatives along curves proof explanation

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

I am curious about the following proof of uniqueness for covariant derivatives along curves.

Proposition: There is precisely one operation $\frac{D}{dt}$ from $C^{\infty}$ vector fields along $c: I=(a,b)\rightarrow M$ ( a curve in $M$) such that

1. $\frac{D(V+W)}{dt}=\frac{DV}{dt}+\frac{DW}{dt}$
2. $\frac{D(fV)}{dt}=\frac{df}{dt}V+f\frac{DV}{dt}$ for $f\in C^{\infty}(I)$
3. If $V_s=Y_{c(s)}$ for some smooth vector field $Y$ defined on a neighbourhood of $c(t)$, then $\frac{DV}{dt}=\nabla_{c'(t)}Y$, where $\nabla$ is a connection.

Proof goes like this;

Choose a coordinate system $(U,x^1,.......,x^n)$ about $c(t)$ then $V(t)=\sum_i^nV^i(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}^i}|_{c(t)}$ where each $V^i\in C^{\infty}(I)$.

Then we must have $\frac{DV}{dt}=\sum_i\frac{D}{dt}(V^i(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}^i}|_{c(t)})$. (Whatever is defined inside the bracket is a local expression, so why are we allowed to define it like that?)

My problems with this:

Why does the above expression make sense? It should be something along the lines of $\frac{DV}{dt}=\sum_i\frac{D}{dt}(V^jg_i)$ where $V^j$ is a smooth function $I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g_i$ is a smooth function $I\rightarrow TM$ such that $g(t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^j}}|_{c(t)}$. But in this case, why would $g$ be a smooth vector field along $c$?

Comment: $\partial/\partial x^i$ is a smooth vector field on the entire coordinate chart $U$. So its restriction to a smooth curve is of course a smooth section of the restriction of $TM$ to that curve. It's a smooth vector field along the curve, but not of course a section of the tangent bundle of the curve itself.

Comment: @TedShifrin My issue is that whatever is inside (....) in $\frac{D(......)}{dt}$, must be a smooth vector field along $c$. That is, in particular, $I\rightarrow \bigcup_{t\in I}T_{c(t)}M$. While it is true that $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}: U\rightarrow TU$, $t \rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}|_{c(t)}$ is a vector field along a segment of $c$, not $c$.

Comment: You stipulated that $U$ was a neighborhood of $c(t)$. I have no idea what that means, if not a neighborhood of the curve. How are $V^i$ functions on $I$ otherwise?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin $U$ is a neighbourhood of $c(t)$ for, which is a point on the manifold $M$ for a fixed $t\in I$, I am not assuming that $c(I)\subseteq U$.

Comment: You should know how to write mathematics more clearly than this by this point in your career. Note that you yourself said $V^i(t)\in C^\infty(I)$, so you are not even consistent with yourself. At any rate, you can extend any locally defined vector field to one defined on the whole interval by the usual bump function tricks, and also prove that the covariant derivative is local (i.e., on the given segment, independent of the extension).

Comment: @TedShifrin I wrote $V^i \in C^{\infty}(I)$.. and I still stand by it. Why can't we have $V^i\in C^{\infty}(I)$ and $t\rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}^i}|_{c(t)}$ not defined on all of $I$?

Answer (score 1):

As Professor Theodore Shifrin pointed out to you, your question is not worded very clearly, because you say that $U$ is only a neighborhood around a point $c(t)$ for fixed $t\in I$ but then you say that the $V^i$'s are functions on $I$ which makes no sense. This is because, if $U$ does not cover the entire curve $c$, the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$'s are not defined on the whole curve and thus writting $V(t)=\sum_i^nV^i(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}^i}|_{c(t)}$ only makes sense for $t\in I_U:=I\cap c^{-1}(U)$. Consequently you would have $V^i\in C^{\infty}(I_U)$.

To cover the whole curve, you would need other coordinate neighborhoods around other points in the curve. In the intersections, the components $V^i$ would transform as components of vector fields under coordinate transformations. Namely, if $\tilde{U}$ is another neighborhood around some point $c(\tilde{t})$ of the curve, with coordinates $(y^1,\ldots,y^n)$, you would have

$$V(t)=\sum_i^nW^i(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}^i}|_{c(t)},\quad t\in I_{\tilde{U}},$$

where $W^i\in C^{\infty}(I_{\tilde{U}})$, with $I_{\tilde{U}}:=I\cap c^{-1}(\tilde{U})$. On the intersection $I_U\cap I_{\tilde{U}}$ you would have coordinate transformations $(y^1(x),\ldots,y^n(x))$ and thus

$$W^i(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}V^j(t),\quad t\in I_U\cap I_{\tilde{U}}.$$

Hope this helps.